Inverse Fourier in two dimensions
I want to compute the Fourier inverse in 2D of the following integral
$\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\Big(\frac{\zeta_1}{\zeta_2}\Big)^k F(\zeta_1,\zeta_2)e^{i(\zeta_1 x_1 + \zeta_2 x_2)}d\zeta_1d\zeta_2, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}.$
My attempt: Let $u = \frac{\zeta_1}{\zeta_2},$ this implies
$\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}u^k F(\zeta_2u,\zeta_2)e^{i\zeta_2(u x_1 + x_2)}\zeta_2d\zeta_2 du = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Bigg(\zeta_2 e^{i\zeta_2x_2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}u^k F(\zeta_2u,\zeta_2)e^{i\zeta_2u x_1}du\Bigg)d\zeta_2, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}.$
How can I continue from here?

It is much easier to just use Fourier transform properties. Pretend for a moment each variable was a constant except one stays a variable. What would its (1D) Fourier transform be in just that variable?

Its not clear to me.

What is $F$?  What are its properties?

$F$ is the Fourier transform of a function say $f$

After keeping one variable constant I get the following: $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(i\zeta_2)^{-k} \frac{\partial^k}{\partial x_1^k}F(x_1, \zeta_2) d\zeta_2$

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(i\zeta_2)^{-k}\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x_1^k}F(x_1,\zeta_2)e^{i\zeta_2x_2}d\zeta_2$
